# Problem with the Blackberry browser

Tags: blackberry

i am working on a application where i have image onwhich when u click it gets navigated to browser with a link but it dont display web page. now i need a code for just displaying a simple web page in blackberry.. is it something to do with simulator and device as i am working with simulator.So kindly help me with it....I am newbie to blackberry.. thank you in advance for help..

Comment: If you're asking a question about Blackberry, try to put in the effort to spell it correctly in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will open up the native browser to the URL you specify:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

String url = "http://www.google.ca";

BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();

browserSession.displayPage(url);

browserSession.showBrowser();

There is a known issue where the browser won't automatically display in various firmware versions.  To get around this, simply call browserSession.showBrowser()